# import gensim and got an TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found

Tags: python, import, typeerror, gensim, attributeerror

I try import gensim library in python3. 
all of the libraries are last version.
in first import got an `TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found`
and in second import got an this error:

```
 import gensim

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e70e92d32c6e> in <module>
----> 1 import gensim

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py in <module>
      3 """
      4 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\transport.py in <module>
     20 NO_SCHEME = ''
     21 
---> 22 _REGISTRY = {NO_SCHEME: smart_open.local_file}
     23 
     24 

AttributeError: module 'smart_open' has no attribute 'local_file'
```

Comment: What command(s) did you use to install `gensim`? (It looks like you're using Anaconda; how did you set up your working environment? If you create a fresh environment and try again, do you get the same error?)

Comment: (Also, if it can be reproduced: what was the exact sequence-of-events & code that generated the original `TypeError`, and that error's full shown stack?)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by this steps:

```
pip install smart-open==1.9.0
pip install gensim==3.4.0
```

this worked for me

Comment: Those don't look like valid `pip` commands, which would usually include the word `install`, and specify versions using an `=`-sign. (And, the package related to `gensim` and in your error message is `smart_open`, not `open-smart`. Also note that gensim-3.4.0 is a version that's over 2 years old, without recent fixes/features.

Comment: @gojomo I used pip install gensim==3.8.3 and pip install smart-open==2.0.0 but take an error. do you know which version of smart-open compatible with gensim 3.8.3?

Comment: Thanks for fixing this answer to include real `pip` commands. However, if it didn't solve your problem, why is it posted as an answer? (If you're still getting the same error as above, perhaps delete this answer, and instead improve the question, or answer questions in the comments, to help solve the original error. If you're getting a new error, explain the steps & exact details/messages of the new error.)